My rosemary leaves are turning yellow then brown
My rosemary leaves have started to turn yellow then brown. I’ve tried changing the watering schedule thinking I gave them too much, but that didn’t help, then I tried adding more water - no change. Finally I checked the roots - no root rot or pests. They were slightly root bound so I trimmed the roots, got them a bigger pot and some new soil but it’s been over two weeks and it seems like the yellowing is getting so much worse. Anyone have any idea what to do?

I can't say what's wrong with it, but I'd suggest rooting some cuttings as soon as possible, from my personal experience. Better yet several months ago, but kinda hard if you didn't do it then. After several years of being (apparently) perfectly happy my big rosemary just declined and died for no apparent reason. Fortunately I had rooted some cuttings earlier and those were fine; When they've gotten bigger I'll likely hedge my bets by taking some more cutings from them...

What is the "water schedule"? How much Sun it get? In my experience (with plants older then 50 years), once per year some old leaves tend to become yellow, and then replaced by new leaves. When did you changed soil last time (or fertilizer)? (but do not overdo it: they like poor soil).

@GiacomoCatenazzi it gets full sun, plus a grow light. I water it around once a week or when the soil is fully dry. I just changed the soil actually when I repotted, so about 2ish weeks ago.
